# manually sorting a paragraph by made-up alphabet with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, alphabetical

I'm trying to sort a paragraph alphabetically, not according to the normal ABC but a made-up one (var order).

I wrote this function and it works great, but only for the first letter of each word - not in-word sorting as well (for example, in correct ABC 'banana' would come before 'birthday').

I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
$("#send").click(function () {
       var text = $("#text").val().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_\s]/g, "").toUpperCase().split(" ");
       var order = ["Q", "B", "K", "D", "H", "V", "Z", "E", "F", "O", "G", "L", "M", "S", "N", "P", "I", "X", "A", "R", "W", "U", "C", "J", "T", "Y"];
       var i, t, j;
       var newText = []; //  will hold the new alphabet
       // function to sort the words:
       for (i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
             for (t = 0; t < text.length; t++) {
                  var firstChar = text[t][0];
                  if (order[i] == firstChar) {
                      newText.push(text[t]);
                  }
             }
       }
       console.log(newText.join(','));
});
```

EDIT:
An example input can be: "Hi dan don't you think that this is awesome",
and I want the output to be: "don't dan hi is awesome this think that you".

Comment: Just curious, would assigning a sorting rank to each letter in the alphabet not work and then sort by rank?

Comment: please add some sample data and the wanted outcome.

Comment: This should be fairly simple to implement, but we would need to see your HTML - or at least the input value - first, along with the expected output

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object with the index of the letters and use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a callback which looks for every letter adn calculates the order.

```js
function foo(text) {
  var text = text.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_\s]/g, "").toUpperCase().split(" "),
      order = "QBKDHVZEFOGLMSNPIXARWUCJTY",
      ref = {};

  order.split('').forEach(function (a, i) { ref[a] = i + 1; });
  text.sort(function (a, b) {
      var i = 0, v;
      do {
          v = (ref[a[i]] || 0) - (ref[b[i]] || 0);
          i++;
      } while (!v)
      return v;
  });
  console.log(text.join(', '));
}

foo('a aa ab b ba bb');
foo('banana birthday');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your algorithm is that it only compares the first letter in each word, but if the letters are the same the algorithm needs to compare the next letter in each word. Here's a solution that uses recursion:

```
function doSort(inputArr) {

  var words = inputArr.slice(0);

  var alphabet = ["Q", "B", "K", "D", "H", "V", "Z", "E", "F", "O", "G", "L", "M", "S", "N", "P", "I", "X", "A", "R", "W", "U", "C", "J", "T", "Y"];

  words.sort(function(item1, item2) {
    return sortRecursive(item1, item2, 0);
  });

  function sortRecursive(item1, item2, idx) {

    if (item1.length <= idx && item2.length <= idx) {
      return 0;
    } else if (item1.length <= idx) {
      return -1;
    } else if (item2.length <= idx) {
      return 1;
    } else if (item1[idx] == item2[idx]) {
      return sortRecursive(item1, item2, idx+1);
    } else {
      return alphabet.indexOf(item1[idx].toUpperCase()) - alphabet.indexOf(item2[idx].toUpperCase());
    }
  }

  return words;
}

var arr = ["banana", "quebec", "bird", "birthday", "birdman", "bird"];
var sortedArr = doSort(arr);

console.log('unsorted',arr);
console.log('sorted', sortedArr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2qgaaozo/